# Getting Email from a Google OAuth ID Token with Golang

Tags: go, oauth

I am following the guide at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth to get OAuth working with my Android app. I have successfully managed to get the ID token and send it to the server, but now I can't get the next step completed with Golang.

How do I simply take this ID token and get the email address from it so that I can log the user in on my server? Any guides and documentation I can find on this are either doing things completely different, referencing an old version of the oauth APIs, or seem to be using a pattern that only works for web. I can't believe it is this hard to get Google sign in working with Google's language.

Comment: please show the code of what you have tried already. you may want to look at [goth](https://github.com/markbates/goth/blob/master/examples/main.go)

Comment: I don't really have anything on the server, I have been able to make 0 progress on what to do with the token that Android gives me. I have successfully been able to call `String idToken = account.getIdToken();`, but now I can't find any useful documentation for receiving that token on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

`String email = payload.getEmail();`

to use this you have to import

`import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;`

all this is given in the page you linked to.

Comment: I need to get the email on the server side. I can get it on the client, but that isn't helpful for logging in with my backend.